# css grid with scrolling

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I created a container made from css `grid`, so I can align the item(s) both vertically or horizontally (depend on the configuration).

The grid item is only one child. I want the child **on the center** when the child is **smaller** than the container and if the child is **bigger**, the container has a **scroller**.

To doing so, I set the grid with `align-items: center`. It works on chrome but on firefox the child got clipped.
Then I did another approach, with `align-content: center`. It works on firefox but not on chrome.
Then I applied both, it doesn't work either.

[image]

I want the grid works on both browsers (or any browser) without platform specific prefix `-webkit-` or `-moz-` or `-whatever-`.

Any idea?

See my code sanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-w4txx?file=/styles.css

```css
:root {
  --conf-horz-align: center;
  --conf-vert-align: center;
}

.container {
  background: pink;
  border: inset 4px blue;

  height: 200px;

  display: grid;
  justify-content: var(--conf-horz-align);

  /* works on chrome but not on firefox */
  /* align-items: var(--conf-vert-align); */

  /* works on firefox but not on chrome */
  align-content: var(--conf-vert-align);

  overflow-y: auto;
}

.window {
  background: lightblue;
  border: inset 16px red;
  width: 400px;
}
.window.short {
  height: 120px;
}
.window.tall {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Another simple example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="window short">
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, quod nesciunt laudantium minus commodi quia corrupti nihil quas dolor eos velit pariatur consequatur error excepturi dicta facilis dolorem numquam vero.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="window tall">
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, quod nesciunt laudantium minus commodi quia corrupti nihil quas dolor eos velit pariatur consequatur error excepturi dicta facilis dolorem numquam vero.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like something wrong is going on with codesandbox itself in your example. CSS file is doubling up and getting conflicted for me. I tried to copy your code outside and it works fine on Chrome, Firefox and Safari with line

```
align-items: var(--conf-vert-align);
```

Check this out: https://testing.accidentallydrawn.com/

Comment: yeah, the codesandbox has frustrated me. Maybe it injected a foreign css into the result.

Comment: Hi, i found the actuall problem: remove height: xxx from the .window.tall and then manually add more contents into .window.tall until it taller than parent. Then add prop overflow:auto into the .window.tall . The window tall will be clipped on firefox.

Comment: I see, I reproduced it and updated my link. But if you are not using overflow:auto on window.tall, then all is fine right? overflow:auto on child makes it overflow within itself from center on all directions, since it is centered, and then scrolling makes no sense anymore.

Comment: actually the child is 3rd party web component. It emit overflow:auto. So i need to overwrite with overflow:visible !important.  Actually it's not clipped, on page inspector the height remain the same, so logically it should be fully visible (i set the height:fit-content).

Comment: I see, interesting. Anyway, if you still have issues with that, feel free to repost your question.

Comment: Hi, i found the side effect setting the child with overflow:visible !important. At the rounded corners (border-radius), the content wont clipped out. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below code. It will work perfectly in all major browsers.
Here I used align-items: centre instead of align-content.

```
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .container {
    background: pink;
    border: inset 4px blue;

    height: 200px;

    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;

    align-items: center;

    overflow-y: auto;
  }

  .window {
    background: lightblue;
    border: inset 16px red;
    width: 400px;
  }
  .window.short {
    height: 120px;
  }
  .window.tall {
    height: 300px;
  }
</style>
```